# Resx culture is null?

Tags: c#, console, .net-3.5

Why system gives error at this `Msg.Culture = new CultureInfo("zh-HK");` line?

Msg is a resx (resource) file.

This is a console program, .Net 3.5, c#.

I tested on my own PC, no issue. It only give me error when I deployed to client PC with a catch, it only give me error when it read certain email from outlook, other email no issue.

Error is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cultureInfo"].ToString()))
{
    if (null != System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture)
    {
        object test = new CultureInfo("zh-HK");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-HK");
    }
    else if (null != Msg.Culture)
    {
        object test = new CultureInfo("zh-HK");
        Msg.Culture = new CultureInfo("zh-HK");
    }
}
```

I can find the resource file name using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()`.

Comment: `(!(null == Msg.Culture))` why would you do that? `(Msg.Culture != null)` is the same but readable

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause, some where above the codes system failed to get data from database and it didn't report the error there and then, it report error at `Msg.Culture = new CultureInfo("zh-HK");` instead.